# How to parse CSV files with double-quoted strings in Julia?

Tags: string, csv, julia

I want to read CSV files where the columns are separated by commas. The columns can be strings and if those strings contain a comma in their content, they are wrapped in double-quotes. Currently I'm loading my data using:

```
file = open("data.csv","r")
data = readcsv(file)
```

But this code code would split the follwing string into 4 pieces whereas it only should be 3:

> 1,"text, more text",3,4

Is there a way in Julia's Standard Library to parse CSV while respecting quoting or do I have to write my own custom solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `readcsv` function in base is super-basic (just blindly splitting on commas).

You will probably be happier with `readtable` from the DataFrames.jl package: http://juliastats.github.io/DataFrames.jl/io.html

To use the package, you just need to Pkg.add("DataFrames"), and then import it with `using DataFrames"

Answer (score 4):

The `readcsv` function in base (0.3 prerelease) can now read quoted columns.

`julia> readcsv(IOBuffer("1,\"text, more text\",3,4"))
1x4 Array{Any,2}:
 1.0  "text, more text"  3.0  4.0`

It is much simpler than `DataFrames`. But may be quicker if you just need the data as an array.